# How to remove all characters but dots and numbers

Tags: bash, formatting, numbers

I need to clear all characters but numbers and dots in a file.

The numbers are formatted as follows:

```
$(24.50)
```

Im using the following code to accomplish the task:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//'
```

It works but the last parenthesis is not removed. After running the code i get:

```
24.50)
```

I should get:

```
24.50
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the following:

`sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'`

Comment: Worked! Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is only matching a single instance of `[^0-9.]*`. Namely, the `$(` at the beginning. In order to get sed to match and replace all instances, you need to put a `g` at the end, as in:

```
sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'
```

The `g` basically means "match this regular expression *anywhere* in the input". By default, it will only match on the first instance it encounters, and then stop.